# TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method tabs

Tags: jquery, tabs

Code looks like this:
http://pastebin.com/e5Qzc1Ba

I caught the following error:
TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'tabs' [http://www.website.ro/functions/tabs.js?ver=3.4.2:14]

Some tabs are not collapsing at all at the moment.
Any clue about the source of this error ?
Thanks.

Comment: solved the case by moving the call to jqueri UI before calling the tabs.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check to make sure jQuery UI has already loaded before you call:

```
 jQuery("#tabs").tabs();
```

You are getting the error because at the point where it's throwing the error, jQuery doesn't have the method named `tabs`.

Comment: i have tried to move the call of the jquery, but my code looks like this: 
  `wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-core');
  wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-tabs');
  wp_register_script('jscolor', get_template_directory_uri().'/_functions/colorpicker/jquery.modcoder.excolor.js');
  wp_enqueue_script('jscolor');
  wp_register_script('tabs', get_template_directory_uri().'/_functions/tabs.js');
  wp_enqueue_script('tabs');
  wp_register_style('theme-options', get_template_directory_uri().'/_functions/theme-options.css');
  wp_enqueue_style('theme-options');`

Comment: so i'm calling tabs.js after jquery-ui-core.

Comment: @laguna You need to verify in the HTML output, not in wordpress code.